# Transform existing XML for Excel with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change existing xml in order to make an excel table from it.

My xml that needs to be changed:

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <cell image="blank.gif">Row1</cell>
    <cell>1</cell>
    <cell>2</cell>
    <cell>3</cell>
    <cell>4</cell>
    <cell>5</cell>
    <cell>6</cell>
    <cell>7</cell>
    <row>
      <cell image="blank.gif">Row1_1</cell>
      <cell>8</cell>
      <cell>9</cell>
      <cell>10</cell>
      <cell>11</cell>
      <cell>12</cell>
      <cell>13</cell>
      <cell>14</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell image="blank.gif">Row1_2</cell>
      <cell>15</cell>
      <cell>16</cell>
      <cell>17</cell>
      <cell>18</cell>
      <cell>19</cell>
      <cell>20</cell>
      <cell>21</cell>
    </row>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell image="blank.gif">Row2</cell>
    <cell>22</cell>
    <cell>23</cell>
    <cell>24</cell>
    <cell>25</cell>
    <cell>26</cell>
    <cell>27</cell>
    <cell>28</cell>
  </row>
</rows>
```

My current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>



  <xsl:template match="rows">
    <xsl:element name="sheetData">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="rowID">
      <xsl:number value="position()" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="row">
      <xsl:attribute name="r">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rowID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>



      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="c">
          <xsl:variable name="colID">
            <xsl:number value="position()" format="A"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:attribute name="r">
            <xsl:value-of  select="concat(string($colID),string($rowID))"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="t">
            <xsl:text>inlineStr</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:element name="is">
            <xsl:element name="t">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output from the transformations:

```
<sheetData>
 <row r="1">
  <c r="A1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>Row1</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="B1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>1</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="C1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>2</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="D1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>3</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="E1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>4</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="F1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>5</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="G1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>6</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="H1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>7</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="I1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>Row1_1891011121314</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="J1" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>Row1_215161718192021</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  </row>
  <row r="2">
  <c r="A2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>Row2</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="B2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>22</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="C2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>23</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="D2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>24</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="E2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>25</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="F2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>26</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="G2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>27</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
  <c r="H2" t="inlineStr">
      <is>
      <t>28</t> 
      </is>
  </c>
 </row>
</sheetData>
```

And a screenshot from the generated excel document:
[image: Screenshot]

So my problem is the nested rows i need to show them exactly like Row1 and Row2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that you want a separate row in the output for each **row** in the input XML, even though the row elements are nested.

To start with then, you need to replace this line

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
```

With this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="cell">
```

This will ensure only the **cell** elements are output in the current row, and the nested **row** elements won't be processed.

Then, after you have created the **row** element with just the **cell** elements, you can look for the nested **row** elements to output these

```
<row>
   <!-- Process Cells -->
</row>
<xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
```

Do note there is no real need to use **xsl:element** to output static named elements, just write out the element directly. Your code can also be tidied up by making use of Attribute Value Templates to create attributes, rather than using **xsl:attribute**

Try the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="rows">
      <sheetData>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
      </sheetData>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <xsl:variable name="rowID">
         <xsl:number level="any" format="1"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <row r="{$rowID}">
         <xsl:for-each select="cell">
            <xsl:variable name="colID">
               <xsl:number value="position()" format="A"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <c t="inlineStr" r="{string($colID)}{string($rowID)}">
               <is>
                  <t>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </t>
               </is>
            </c>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<sheetData>
   <row r="1">
      <c t="inlineStr" r="A1">
         <is>
            <t>Row1</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="B1">
         <is>
            <t>1</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="C1">
         <is>
            <t>2</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="D1">
         <is>
            <t>3</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="E1">
         <is>
            <t>4</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="F1">
         <is>
            <t>5</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="G1">
         <is>
            <t>6</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="H1">
         <is>
            <t>7</t>
         </is>
      </c>
   </row>
   <row r="2">
      <c t="inlineStr" r="A2">
         <is>
            <t>Row1_1</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="B2">
         <is>
            <t>8</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="C2">
         <is>
            <t>9</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="D2">
         <is>
            <t>10</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="E2">
         <is>
            <t>11</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="F2">
         <is>
            <t>12</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="G2">
         <is>
            <t>13</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="H2">
         <is>
            <t>14</t>
         </is>
      </c>
   </row>
   <row r="3">
      <c t="inlineStr" r="A3">
         <is>
            <t>Row1_2</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="B3">
         <is>
            <t>15</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="C3">
         <is>
            <t>16</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="D3">
         <is>
            <t>17</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="E3">
         <is>
            <t>18</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="F3">
         <is>
            <t>19</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="G3">
         <is>
            <t>20</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="H3">
         <is>
            <t>21</t>
         </is>
      </c>
   </row>
   <row r="4">
      <c t="inlineStr" r="A4">
         <is>
            <t>Row2</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="B4">
         <is>
            <t>22</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="C4">
         <is>
            <t>23</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="D4">
         <is>
            <t>24</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="E4">
         <is>
            <t>25</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="F4">
         <is>
            <t>26</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="G4">
         <is>
            <t>27</t>
         </is>
      </c>
      <c t="inlineStr" r="H4">
         <is>
            <t>28</t>
         </is>
      </c>
   </row>
</sheetData>
```

Comment: There is a problem with row r attribute they need to be different.Your output show rows with same r and the excel document can't read those rows.

Comment: Good point! I've tweaked my answer so that the rows are now numbered 1 to 4 as required.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is to import the XML as is.

1. Switch to XML-map (dev tools, xml Source, [the xml map should open on the right handside])
2. Delete all of them
3. Then you can select with rightlick "add" were to input the data into the Excel sheet