# Create an Excel Spreadsheet in Workflow CRM 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am developing a solution for CRM 2013 Online. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Create a CodeActivity (Workflow). When triggered, the workflow will query data and create a custom excel spreadsheet.
2. Attach the spreadsheet to the record.

I tried using ILMerge to merge an excel library with the workflow library, the workflow library will call methods in excel library to create a spreadsheet. Then, I registered the merged library to upload to CRM. Everything is OK, but when I trigger the workflow, I get an exception `System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error`. This is because the workflow is  registered in Sandbox and the excel library uses some system libraries underhood, the CRM Online Server doesn’t allow this.

So far, I have tried a few excel libraries such as EPPlus, NPOI, ExcelPackage, OpenXML.

Could you advise me how to achieve this?

Thanks

UPDATE: I found a solution that fits my requirement. I have created XML file using OpenXML format on MSDN and `MemoryStream` without using any external library.

Comment: Do you really need to create a full fledged Excel workbook or could you just create a Excel-ish Xml document? Maybe your solution could be to use an Xslt transformation to create the final Excel Xml spreadsheet.

Comment: The spreadsheet have custom format like a time table with activities expand through multiple columns and rows. I think Excel XML will work. Is there any libraries support this? Or do I have to deal with XML manually?

Comment: Maybe [Transform existing XML for Excel with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13191907/205233) could be starting point.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at that.

Comment: If there's more to your desired Excel output you could try to reverse engineer a spreadsheet created in Excel and check the underlying Xml.